# Importing perforce stream into the root directory of another stream

Tags: perforce, p4v

I have two depots with one stream each:

- **//DepotA/StreamA**
- **//DepotB/StreamB**.

I want to import the contents of **//DepotA/StreamA** into the root directory of **//DepotB/StreamB**.

The workspace should look like this:

```
workspace\
├─ [StreamB files]
├─ [StreamA files]
```

I have tried this using the View settings of //DepotB/StreamB:

```
share ...
import ./... //DepotA/StreamA/...
```

But this doesn't import any files into the workspace from StreamA.

If I instead write

```
share ...
import StreamAFiles/... //DepotA/StreamA/...
```

I get

```
workspace\
├─ [StreamB files]
├─ StreamAFiles\
├─ ├─ [StreamA files]
```

so I think I'm on the right track.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to import an arbitrary depot path into the root of a stream would be:

```
import ... //DepotA/StreamA/...
```

Note that you can't combine this with a `share ...`; each path in the stream needs to be mapped to a specific location in the depot, and where they conflict, one will override the other.

You could have them in parallel directories by doing something like:

```
Paths:
    share ...
    import StreamA/... //DepotA/StreamA/...

Remapped:
    ... StreamB/...
```

That will give you a mapping like:

```
workspace\
├─ StreamA\
├─ ├─ [//DepotA/StreamA files]
├─ StreamB\
├─ ├─ [//DepotB/StreamB files, EXCEPT FOR //DepotB/StreamB/StreamA]
```

If you want to merge streamA's files into the depot namespace of streamB, you can do that by branching the actual files (rather than mapping the depot namespace of streamA into streamB's client namespace).  Use a regular old `share` path so that you can submit files freely to `streamB`:

```
Stream: //DepotB/StreamB
Paths:
    share ...
```

and then within a client of that stream you can do:

```
p4 merge -F //DepotA/StreamA/... //DepotB/StreamB/...
p4 resolve
p4 submit
```

Comment: When I use import ... //DepotA/StreamA/... perforce appears to ignore the depot path and instead imports every stream on the server into the workspace. I should have mentioned that the server has many other depots.

Could you perhaps also explain why the `share ...` directive cannot be used with the first solution? I'm having a tough time understanding the documentation.

Comment: On the first question: you might have a typo (like you did `import ... //...` accidentally).  On the second -- you can do `share ...` or `import ...` but not both, because each unique path in the stream needs to have one specific source.  If you do `import ... <something>` then there's noplace for the parent's files (`share ...`) to go.  Putting them in separate subdirectories is probably what you want to do.